# How to publish to a particular Mobile push notification endpoint from Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, push-notification, amazon-sns

I have a SNS mobile push notification service configured in AWS with FCM. I am able to send push notifications to a particular endpoint from the console with publish message.

But I want to publish a message to a particular endpoint from a Lambda function. I wrote a Lambda and gave necessary functions. But when I try to run the lambda there is no error thrown and no push notification actions.

Here is my code,

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sns = new AWS.SNS();


exports.handler = async (event) => {

var params = {
    TargetArn:'arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:<my_user_id>:app/GCM/<my_sns_projectname>/<device-token>',
    Message:'Success!!! ',
    Subject: 'TestSNS'
};

await sns.publish(params , (err,data)=>{
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error sending a message " + err);
    } else {
        console.log("Sent message: " + data.MessageId);

    }
})
};
```

I am a beginner, some help pls :)

Comment: It might be a matter of insufficient permission. Maybe this can be of help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64670151/360674

Comment: Hi @Christian, currently i am running the lambda with SNS full access.

Answer (score 0):

Voila!! This worked for me!

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sns = new AWS.SNS();


const params = {
    TargetArn:'arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:<my_user_id>:app/GCM/<my_sns_projectname>/<device-token>',
    Message:JSON.stringify('Success!!! '),
    Subject: 'TestSNS'
};

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const publishPromise = sns.publish(params).promise();
    await publishPromise.then((response) => { 
        console.log("SENT")
        callback(null, "Message published.");
    }, (err) => {
      console.log("We had an error");
      console.log(err);
      callback("Message wasn’t able to publish.");
    });
};
```